# Bad Image Format VS DLL Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, c, dll

I've got a problem loading a C DLL through a C# wrapper class. I have done some research, and I have not yet gotten a satisfactory solution from doing any of the below

- Changing my solution's target platform.
- Changing my project's target platform.
- Changing the platform in the configuration's manager.

The C DLL that I'm trying to use is 64 bit, so I initially tried setting everything to 64 bit and accessing the DLL through my wrapper class. When I did this, I got a DLLNotFoundException. Perplexed because my DLL was definitely on the build path, I tried setting everything to 32 bit, at which point, it looks like my DLL was found, but I was getting a Bad Image Format Exception on the same line.

What could this mean, and where should I go from here?

The library I'm trying to use is the DualAlign I2KRetina library; trying to adapt it to C#. The experimental code that I'm running is very simple (below). I am not presenting the wrapper class (which I got from DualAlign) because it's pretty large, and I have no reason to doubt that it is working (yet) =).

```
class TestImage2
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        TestMontageMethod();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public unsafe static void TestMontageMethod()
    {
        IntPtr license_file_path = DA_CSharpCls.da_i2k_expected_license_path(); 
    }
}
```

The line that's giving me trouble is the license_file_path assignment. A big thank you to everyone who contributes!

Comment: Is your configuration managers platform set to Any CPU?

Comment: I'm not sure you want the () on the IntPtr assignment line, unless the da_i2k_expected_license_path method returns a method pointer.

Comment: Also, in my understanding, DLL and application architecture must match.  If your DLL is 64 bits, you must build your application as 64 bits to use it (which is why you get the BadImageFormat exception in 32-bit code).  Focus on the "not found" error.

Comment: The "not found" message usually means "can't be loaded", so, check your dependencies and everything so you are sure your dll is loading properly

Comment: Terje: It was indeed =).
Lotharyx and fernando.reyes: you guys were right. The DLL was not loading because it was not being found. I made a new project, moved the dll to a different folder (it was originally in the project's bin), changed my environment path accordingly, and voila! The code started working without crashing. Not sure why it wasn't being found in the project's bin directory. Thanks to everyone for contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've fixed the BadImageFormat exception by compiling in 64-bit; now it seems like either you  can't find the DLL or it is missing a dependency.

First thing to check is that the DLL exists in the path or in the output directory if your build; keep in mind that it may be different for each build (x86, AnyCPU and x64) so the library may need to be copied to that directory either by you manually or through the reference properties in VS.

If you've established that the DLL does exist, then it is likely a dependency issue. Download the 64bit version of [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and it will show you what is missing.

Comment: Though the issue was solved by the time I read this, I admit that this post would've most likely lead me to the answer, so it gets the green checkmark =). Thanks, Allan.

Comment: Glad you're up and running!

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the framework version difference between two DLL. This can cause issue sometime.

Comment: It was not the case this time, but thank you for the pointer! I will keep my eyes on that.